# Can I prove Heine-Borel theorem as this?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am self-learning general topology without any teacher who guides me. So I have to post my "homework" here, to check if my proof is correct.

#### Lemma

Let $(X, \rho)$ to be a totally bounded metric space. For any infinite sequence $u: I \to X$, there exists a subsequence $w: J \to X$ which is Cauchy.

**Proof.** Let $(M, \rho')$ to be a compact metric space, and let $(X, \rho)$ to be its subspace. As $M$ is compact, then for any infinite sequence $u: I \to A \subseteq M$, there exists an infinite subsequence $w: J \to A \subseteq M$ such that $w$ converges to a point $x \in M$. As $X \subseteq M$, we can suppose $u: I \to X$, then there must be a subsequence $w: J \to X$ converges to a point $x \in M$. Thus, $x$ is a limit point, in other words, for any $\varepsilon \in \mathbb R_{> 0}$, there exists $k \in J$ such that the image $w[I_{\ge k}] \subseteq B_{\rho'}(x, \varepsilon)$. Thus, for any $n, m \in J_{\ge k}$, $\rho(w(m), w(n)) < \varepsilon$.

---

#### Theorem: Heine-Borel theorem

A metric space is compact, if and only if it is totally bounded and complete.

**Proof.** Let $(X, \rho)$ be a complete and compact metric space, and let $(A, \rho_A)$ be its subspace.

First we prove $\Rightarrow$. If $A$ is compact, then $A$ is closed in $X$. Suppose $A$ is not complete. As $X$ is complete, let sequence $u: I \to A$ converges to $x \in X \setminus A$. As $x$ is a limit point of $A$ but it is not an element of $A$, $A$ is not closed. This is contradicted to the assumption we have. Thus $A$ must be complete.

Now we prove $\Leftarrow$. As $A$ is totally bounded, for any infinite sequence $u: I \to A$, there exists a subsequence $w: J \to A$ which is Cauchy. As $A$ is complete, then $w$ converges to a point $a \in A$. Thus $A$ is sequentially compact. As $(A, \rho_A)$ is a metric space, it is compact.

Comment: So you already know the theorem that any totally bounded metric space $(X,\rho)$ is a subspace of a compact metric space $(M,\rho’)$? Do you also know that $\pho’$ restricted to $X$ is $\rho$ again? That would give an easier proof.

Comment: Thank you @Henno Brandsma! It means, in the Lemma I give if M is compact, then of course we can find a sequence u converges to an x in M, as ρ´ restricts to ρ, if I can let x to be a limit point of X, then u can be considered as a Cauchy sequence in X. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Complete implies closed in a larger space; see my answer below. Your lemma is shown even easier by noting that the convergent subsequence is a Cauchy subsequence right away. Why don’t you do that. In any metric space convergent implies Cauchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that a compact metric space is complete and totally bounded (I assume you already know this); this takes care of one direction in your version of Heine-Borel. (The second is almost by definition, and the first uses that a Cauchy sequence which has a convergent subsequence (converging to some $p$) itself converges to $p$, and we use compact $\implies$ sequentially compact in metric spaces).

But in your lemma you use a result which gives the other direction quite directly: suppose that $(X,\rho)$ is totally bounded and complete. Then there is a compact metric space $(K, \rho’)$ such that $X \subseteq K$ and $\rho’ \restriction_{X \times X}= \rho$. But then by completeness $X$ is closed in $K$ and hence compact (if $X$ were not closed in $K$ we’d have some $p \in K\setminus X$ and a sequence $(x_n)_n \to p$ in $K$, but then $(x_n)_n$ is Cauchy in $(X,\rho)$ too (by the assumption on the metrics) and must converge in $X$ but this would contradict the unicity of limits in $(K,\rho’)$ QED).

That way I do not have to use that sequentially compact $\implies$ compact for metric spaces at all.

Comment: @Wenchuan that doesn’t help, does it?

Comment: I think yes, but I am try to rearrange the proof in your way. Still need some time :P

Comment: @Wenchuan the lemma can be proved from the definition of total boundedness alone. No need for a compact containing space. If $X$ is totally bounded we can take it’s completion which is still totally bounded etc.

Comment: The first thing I am sure I got it is, for the "only if..." in my proof of Heine-Borel theorem, I can let X be in a compact super-space (that is your K), and this makes X closed in K. In this case, the lemma is redundant.

Comment: @Wenchuan many ways lead to Rome.

Comment: Thank you! This is the first time I'm learning math from a real person. It feels awesome! @Henno Brandsma